# Require country in lightning:inputAddress

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I would like to require the country field in a `lightning:inputAddress` tag.
The `required` atttribute is set to `true` but the only affected fields are the street, the postal code and the city.

Is there any way to enable this validation on the other fields aswell? (Country and province)

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce docs:

> When you set required="true", a red asterisk is displayed on every
>   address field to indicate that they are required. An error message is
>   displayed below a field if a user interacted with it and left it
>   blank. **The required attribute is not enforced and you must validate it
>   before submitting a form that contains an address compound field.**

Thus you have to manually check if the values are blank or not. You can do that using JS

```
({
    handleClick: function (cmp, event) {
        var address = cmp.find("myaddress");
        var isValid = address.checkValidity();
        if(isValid) {
            alert("Creating new address");
        }
        else {
            address.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        }
    }
})
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/documentation

Comment: The documentation is wrong, it doesn't display the asterisk over Country and Province and doesn't check these fields when using `checkValidity`.